# Struggling with adding app to INSTALLED_APPS Django

Tags: django, web

I have no idea, this always worked for me, but without motivation, it's not working now.
what i did:

1. I created my project
2. I created my app
3. I added my config to INSTALLED_APPS
4. I get this error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'champ.apps' does not contain a class 'ChampConfigcorsheaders'. Choices are: 'ChampConfig'.`

My project looks like this:

- Championship_3bi

  - champ

    - all the files of the app
  - Championship_3bi

    - all the files of the project

This is my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'champ.apps.ChampConfig'  #this is the line that create the "error"
    'corsheaders',
]
```

I've also tried to do `champ.apps.ChampConfigcorsheaders` but it didnt work. 

This is my `champ/apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ChampConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'champ'
```

i searched for everything but looks like i was the only one who get this error.

The reason why it does not work is for the weird name of my project?

Why it is not working for only this project?

im done

Comment: have you tried adding 'champ' alone, such that it becomes 

   'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'champ',
   'corsheaders',

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `,`:

```
    'champ.apps.ChampConfig',
    'corsheaders',
```

Comment: please end my life

Comment: hahahah this happens! I am actually working on something very similar and asked a question on here, do you mind checking it out? I feel like you could help me

Comment: oh ok, link the question, ill give it a look